# Reverse Java random seed using 81 calls to nextInt with a bound of 4?

Tags: cryptanalysis, pseudo-random-generator

I'm trying to reverse the Java random seed using 81 calls to `nextInt(bound)` with a `bound` of 4. I am wondering if it is at all possible to reverse the random seed.

In this situation Java's random number generator is called 81 times, and for each call I know if the returned value is either `0` or not `0`. Looking at the `int nextInt(int bound)` method, here is the relevant code:

```
int r = next(31);
if ((bound & (bound-1)) == 0)  // i.e., bound is a power of 2
    r = (int)((bound * (long)r) >> 31);
```

where `r` is the returned value, and `next(31)` is the next pseudo-random value using 31 bits. Here is that `next` method:

```
protected int next(int bits) {
    long oldseed, nextseed;
    AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
    do {
        oldseed = seed.get();
        nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
    } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

where the multiplier is a constant `0x5DEECE66DL`, `addend` is `0xBL`, `mask` is `(1L << 48) - 1`. Here, `0x` indicates a hexadecimal value, and the `L` is there to make the literal value a Java `long` (64-bit).

---

In Java, `int` is always 32 bits in size. Furthermore `AtomicLong` is a multi-threading related construct that simply represents a 64 bit `long` in this code. The mask makes sure that the value never exceeds 48 bits. The loop construct and `!compareAndSet` can be entirely replaced by a simple `seed = nextSeed`.

Basically then, the seed $s$ is updated using:

$$s \gets (\mathtt{5DEECE66D}_{16} \cdot s + \mathtt{B}_{16}) \bmod {2^{48}}$$

after which the two most significant bits of the 48 bit value $s$ are returned.

---

I don't know if this is possible, since so many bits are dropped, but I have seen this done with calls to `nextInt(10)`.

Sorry if there is anything I left out or if this is too vague, this is my first cryptography post.

Comment: Please note that this is **not** Java's `SecureRandom` implementation which should always provide a cryptographically secure random number generator. This is about `java.util.Random` which is a small non-secure random generator. Beware that `Random` also acts as an *interface definition* for `SecureRandom` but the `next` method is *overridden* in (i.e. replaced for) `SecureRandom` - so it doesn't apply there.

Comment: Note that the Java RNG is actually [a well known RNG called DRAND48](https://youtu.be/45Oet5qjlms?t=1491), which was described for the PDP11 in 1983, a rather modern computer in 1970.

Answer (score 3):

The $48$-bit state $s_i$ evolves per a Linear Congruential Random Number Generator, with modulus $n=2^{48}$, multiplier $a=\mathtt{5DEECE66D}_{16}$, and additive constant $b=\mathtt B_{16}$; that is $s_i=(a\cdot s_{i-1}+b)\bmod2^{48}$. We are given the OR $r_i$ of its two upper bits for $i\in[1,81]$, or equivalently the $81$ booleans $s_i\ge2^{46}$. Our goal is to find $s_0$: if the Java default generator was explicitly seeded, $s_0\oplus a$ is the low-order 48 bits of the given `long` seed.

The $81$ givens yield about $-81\left(\frac14\log_2(\frac14)+\frac34\log_2(\frac34)\right)\approx65.7$ bit of information, which should be typically ample to pinpoint a single $48$-bit seed.

A most brute force solution to the problem enumerates all the $s_0$ in $[0,2^{48})$, and for increasing $i$ computes the $s_i$ and eliminates a candidate $s_0$ as soon as there's a mismatch between a bit $r_i$ and the condition $s_i\ge2^{46}$. That's feasible, and particularly easy to distribute on multiple threads/CPUs/GPUs/FPGAs. The rest of this answer illustrates the NSA saying (popularized by Bruce Schneier): *Attacks always get better; they never get worse*.

---

Notice that we can compute for $z\in[-81,81]$ the $48$-bit constants $a_z$ and $b_z$ such that $s_{i+z}=(a_z\cdot s_i+b_z)\bmod2^{48}$. We have
$$\begin {align}
a_0&=1&b_0&=0\\
a_{z+1}&=a\cdot a_z\bmod2^{48}&b_{z+1}&=(a\cdot b_z+b)\bmod2^{48}\\
a_{-1}&=a^{-1}\bmod2^{48}=\mathtt{DFE05BCB1365}_{16}&b_{-1}&=a_{-1}\cdot (-b)\bmod2^{48}\\
a_{z-1}&=a_{-1}\cdot a_z\bmod2^{48}&b_{z-1}&=a_{-1}\cdot (b_z-b)\bmod2^{48}
\end{align}$$
This allows computing directly any $s_j$ from any $s_i$, by taking $z=j-i$. That's put to use in the following optimizations:

- Pick an $i$ with $r_i=0$ and reorganize the search by walking $s_i$ in the interval to $[0,2^{46})$, then compute $s_0$ from $s_i$. That's a welcome gain by a factor of $4$.
- We most likely¹ can pick the above $i$ such that $r_i=r_{i+1}=0$. The condition $s_{i+1}<2^{46}$ (which must hold) changes rarely when incrementing $s_i$: it holds true for about $2^{46}/a\approx2791$ consecutive values, then is false for an interval about three times longer, that we can skip, giving a speedup by a factor next to $4$.

At that stage of optimization, we explore $2^{44}$ values of $s_i$. I guesstimate² we can run faster than $2^6$ cycles/value tested on a core of a modern x64 desktop CPU. With a single $2^2$-core CPU at $2^{31}$ Hz, that would be $2^{17}$ seconds (1.5 day for the full exploration), and half that on average.

We can do better, but be warned that *premature optimization is the root of all evils* (Donald Knuth). We most often are able to make good use of the fact that $a_{-67}$ is small: when we can find $i,z$ with $r_i=r_{i+1}+r_{i-67}=0$, that allows getting down to $2^{42}$ values searched at cost of a further sub-division of the search sub-intervals for $s_i$ into sub-sub-intervals of width $2^{46}/a_{-67}\approx394$.

We often are able to further subdivide at least once or even twice, each time gaining another reduction by a factor of $4$ of the number of $a_i$ to test. We want to explore the usefulness of such subdivision for each $s_{i+z}$ with $r_{i+z}=0$. The better choices have the highest width $\approx2^{46}/\min(a_z,2^{48}-a_z)$ for the interval of $a_i$ with $s_{i+z}<2^{46}$. In particular, we might be able to use that $2^{46}/a_{19}\approx60$ or $2^{46}/(2^{48}-a_{-12})\approx60$. But we'll quickly get hit by the law of diminishing returns.

---

**Update**: There must be better methods. Something at least quite close was studied by Alan M. Frieze, Johan Hastad, Ravi Kannan, Jeffrey C. Lagarias, and Adi Shamir, [*Reconstructing Truncated Integer Variables Satisfying Linear Congruences*](http://www.csc.kth.se/~johanh/fhkls.pdf), in [SIAM Journal on Computing, 1988](https://doi.org//10.1137/0217016).

---

¹ In the very unlikely case (I'm not even sure it is possible) that there's no $i$ with $r_i=r_{i+1}=0$, the simplest of several possible fallbacks is to pick $i$ and $z$ with $r_i=r_{i+z}=0$ and the smallest $a_z$ possible; that will often be $z=-67$ or $z=19$. The reduction in number of $s_i$ scanned is the same, but we'll more often change sub-intervals.

² When $s_i$ increases in a sub-interval, we want to quickly update at least one $s_j$ that we'll always test. An update of $s_j$ cost one addition of $a_{j-i}$ and a mask³. We'll pick $j$ with $r_j=0$, which will leave only one out of $4$ values of $s_i$ needing more scrutiny. For these, we sequentially compute and test the many other $s_{i+z}$ that we could still have wrong, of course stopping at the first mismatch and first testing $z$ with $r_{i+z}=0$. Each additional $z$ requires a multiplication by $a_z$. If that's too costly, we'll want to maintain one or a few more $s_k$ by addition.

³ A simple micro-optimization maintains $2^{16}s_i$ over a $64$-bit variable, saving the masking. The comparison becomes against $2^{62}$, also implementable as a $62$-bit right shift and a test for zero.

Comment: I will test this out today or tomorrow, if it works within a reasonable time frame (like within a week max) I will mark this as an answer with the time it took me to run.

Comment: I've talked with some people who have a lot more experience than me in LCG, and they showed me a lot better of a method. Apparently if the output is 0, the top 2 bits are 0. Calls can also be combined into another LCG. This worked in 20 minutes. Another used said faster code can be made using lattices, but it would take a lot longer to write.

Comment: @Big_Bad_E: yes if the output of nextInt(4) is 0, the top 2 bits of the state after that are 0. The answer's method is based on that. I do not get _"Calls can also be combined into another LCG"_, what calls? 20 minutes would be very hard with my method, I wish I knew more about how this was achieved: was the input only 81 bits as in the question (more inputs or choosing the indexes helps a lot)? Was the seed an arbitrary 48-bit value?

Comment: It was actually less than 81 bits, and the seed was 48-bit. I will upload the cl file if it works in a bit.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/510201738003873793/669287428275699749/SequenceToGPU.java They used this to auto-generate cl files to crack the random seed.

Comment: @Big_Bad_E: this seem to generate OpenCL code to be run using a GPU. No wonder the result is found fast!

Comment: Oh, you weren’t thinking about using OpenCL. Yea, that’s why, this operation is so easy to parallelize it works really well.